# Importing @tailwind base is causing a component not to render on screen

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use an image map library for my Next.js project. I've been experiencing issues having the component show up on screen, and after some investigating it became apparent that the reason for the component not showing (or showing) depends on whether I include `@tailwind base` or not in my `globals.css`.

I'm trying to find useful information that might help me understand what may be the cause of that but haven't been able to come up with anything useful.

I thought that a solution for now might be copying this component into my code, and placing it in a scope outside of what I've assigned to tailwind (as in directly in my root folder, rather than inside `app` or `components`) but that hasn't helped.

What might be causing this behavior?

This is the library I'm trying to add to my code
https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper

I am simply using the example implementation code from the library now.

EDIT: I've checked the tree in both cases. This is what I get with @tailwind base:
https://ibb.co/X8ZNT5f

And this is what we get without it:
https://ibb.co/ryN0KXz

If I manually change both the image & canvas heights & widths to the correct size of the image (640 * 480), then the component renders just fine. I need to understand what about tailwind causes these values to be 0 and how do I override it.